# Getting DayOfWeek from ComboBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, combobox, dayofweek

I'm trying to find a way of using `DayOfWeek.Monday` but by selecting it on a form.

So if the user selects Tuesday from a drop down combo box, then programmatically it will be `DayOfWeek.Tuesday`.

This is the current code:

```
Do Until dtpEndMonth.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday
```

I want to say something like:

```
Do Until dtpEndMonth.DayOfWeek = DayOfweek.Me.Controls("ComboBox1").Value
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If this static approach is viable, you could parse the string directly to the DayOfWeek-Enum:

```
Dim dayOfWeekValue = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
Dim dayOfWeek = DirectCast(System.Enum.Parse(GetType(DayOfWeek), dayOfWeekValue), DayOfWeek)
```

Comment: It says 'FindControl' is not a member of form1??

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be by doing something like this:

```
' On Form_Load()
Dim daysOfWeek = {New KeyValuePair(Of DayOfWeek, String)(DayOfWeek.Sunday, "Sunday"),
                  New KeyValuePair(Of DayOfWeek, String)(DayOfWeek.Monday, "Monday"),
                  ...,
                  New KeyValuePair(Of DayOfWeek, String)(DayOfWeek.Saturday, "Satruday")}

Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = daysOfWeek
Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
...
```

Then when you want to get the selected value:

```
Dim selectedDayOfWeek = CType(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue, DayOfWeek)
```

This approach leverages the ability to have a `ComboBox` have both a Display and a Value Member (via the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx) property), so that when the user selects a human-friendly display value, they are actually selecting a "data value" under the covers, which is what your code deal with.

Note: I didn't test this code, so there may be typos.  If you need any clarifications or corrections, let me know.

Comment: I see where you're going with this - just a bit stuck...

It says "Cannot bind to the new display member. Parameter name: newDisplayMember" on me.combobox1.valuemember = "Key".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you paste your code on pastebin and provide a link?  I'm guessing it's just a typo somewhere.  I'll help you track it down.

Comment: Thank you - I've been side tracked on another project at the moment... but I will be back one day!